# How to get underlying view after a gesture is caught on a row of ListView 

Tags: android, listview, gesture

**Scenario:**
There is a Listview. A user can either swipe or tap on it for interaction. On tap, it opens a new Activity that shows details of an item from the Listview. On Swipe, it toggles state of the item, say fro "read" to "unread" and vice-versa.

The gesture is caught using a GestureListener

```
    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener{ 

    // Detect a single-click and call my own handler.
    @Override 
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        int pos = lv.pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
        myOnItemClick(pos);
        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { 
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) 
            return false; 
        ListView lv = getListView();
        int pos = lv.pointToPosition((int)e1.getX(), (int)e1.getY());
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
            Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) { 
            onRTLFling(e2, pos); 
        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
            Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) { 
            onLTRFling(e2, pos); 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 

}
```

*Method for tap:*

```
 private void myOnItemClick(int position) {
    //String str = MessageFormat.format("Item clicked = {0,number}", position);
    //Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int topChild = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

    //String text = ((TextView) lv.getChildAt(position + topChild)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on item: " + (position + topChild) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

*Method for left to right fling:*

```
private void onLTRFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, int position) {
    String text = ((TextView) lv.getChildAt(position)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Left-to-right fling on item: " + position + "|" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
    cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
    lv.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
}
```

*Method for right to left fling*

```
private void onRTLFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, int position) {
    String text = ((TextView) lv.getChildAt(position)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Left-to-right fling on item: " + position + "|" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
    cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
    lv.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
}
```

Now, in all the three methods I want to get access to the view related to the row (on which gesture has been performed). I tried using `listView.getChild(position)`, where "position" is "pos" that I calculate in "MyGestureDetetor" class. It works fine until the listview is scrolled. I found out that the position changes every time the listview is scrolled.

Is there a way using which I can access underlying view and manipulate it as with "onItemClickListener"?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing.  I wanted to implement an action on a view based on a gesture being detected.  For me it was to just change the background color or border of a ListView item when enough of a movement was detected.

The problem with using 
     int pos = lv.pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
     View v = lv.getChildAt(pos) 
is that the view does not necessarily correlate to the position of the item.  So basically the 'pos' variable is the index of the data behind the view, not necessarily the view itself.

So, for the current solution it may be easier, although arguably not as clear, to put the extra flags in the data object and respond to whatever changes you want to make to the view in the ListView Adapter .getView() section.